# Counting rows in mysql database

Tags: mysql, count, row, mysql-num-rows

I want to count from the row with the least value to the row with a specific value.
For example,

```
Name / Point
--------------------
Pikachu  / 7
Voltorb / 1
Abra / 4
Sunflora / 3
Squirtle / 8
Snorlax / 12
```

I want to count to the 7, so I get the returned result of '4' (counting the rows with values 1, 3, 4, 7)

I know I should use count() or mysql_num_rows() but I can't think of the specifics.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with MySQL, then you could ORDER BY Point:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE Point < 7 ORDER BY Point ASC
```

If you want to know all about ORDER BY, check out the w3schools page: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Just in case you want to only count the rows based on the Point values:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE Point < 7 GROUP BY Point
```

Comment: "row with the least value to the row with a specific value" makes me think that he wants to make sure that there is some order in the Point values, not just in this specific case where they properly align.

Comment: If you return only the row count, the order is useless.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this :

```
 select count(*) from mytable where Point<=7;
```

`Count(*)` counts all rows in a set.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to get rows falling between range of values :

```
select count(*) from table where Point >= least_value and Point<= max_value
```